# questions in adding jbutton to jtable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jbutton

i've a system that has jtable and i need to put jbuttons on the table. i tried searching all over the internet but this is the only code i understand *a little bit*. this is the site where i found the code [JButton in JTable Cell: How to add, assign or fill up JTable’s Cell with JButton and then add ActionListener to enable Click event for that JButtons in JTable cell.](https://allaboutbasic.com/2011/02/19/jbutton-in-jtable-cell-how-to-add-assign-or-fill-up-jtable%E2%80%99s-cell-with-jbutton-and-then-add-actionlistener-to-enable-click-event-for-that-jbuttons-in-jtable-cell/)

and here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.*;

class ButtonInJTable extends JFrame{
    private JPanel topPanel,topPanel1;
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane,scrollPane1;
    private String[] columnNames= new String[3];
    private String[][] dataValues=new String[3][3] ;
    JButton button = new JButton();

    public ButtonInJTable(){
        setTitle("Button in JTable Cell");
        setSize(300,300);
        topPanel= new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(topPanel);
        columnNames=new String[] {"Column 1" , "Column 2" , "Column 3"};
        dataValues = new String[][] {{"1","2",}, {"4","5",}, {"7","8",}};
        TableModel model=new myTableModel("owntable");
        table =new JTable( );
        table.setModel(model);
        table.getColumn("Column 3").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
        table.getColumn("Column 3").setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));
        scrollPane=new JScrollPane(table);
        topPanel.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);  

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Button Clicked in JTable Cell");
            }
        });
    }

    class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {
        public ButtonRenderer() {
            //setOpaque(true);
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
            return this;
        }
    }

    class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
        private String label;

        public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
            super(checkBox);
        }

        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            label = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
            button.setText(label);
            return button;
        }

        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return new String(label);
        }
    }

    public class myTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
        String dat;
        JButton button=new JButton("");

        myTableModel(String tname){
            super(dataValues,columnNames);
            dat=tname;
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row,int cols){
            if( dat=="owntable"){
                if(cols==0){return false;}
            }
            return true;
        }
    }         

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ButtonInJTable mainFrame=new ButtonInJTable();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }         
}
```

i still haven't understand this code fully so i just want to ask some few questions:

**What does this mean?**

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
            return this;
        }
```

and this:

```
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
                label = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
                button.setText(label);
                return button;
        }
```

**Why should be there a `checkbox`?**

```
public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
            super(checkBox);
        }
```

**Base on the code above, how can i have separate `actionlistener` for different buttons?**

thank you for any of your answers :)

Comment: `this is the only code i understand a little bit.` - Check out [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/). It may be easier to use since all you need to do is provide the Action to be invoked when the button is clicked. `how can i have separate actionlistener for different buttons?` - why would you have different Actions since the data in each row is of the same format? If the Action is different based on the state of the data in the row, then you can build that logic into your Action.

Comment: If you want to know how renderers/editors work, then check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concepts: Renderers and Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Comment: @camickr why is there a checkbox?

Comment: @bruh: There are several different types, that the `JTable / the renderer` can interpret: String, Date, some number formats, ... , Boolean. Boolean get's interpreted by a `JCheckBox`, which can have either a tick in it ( = 1) or no tick in it ( = 0), which is the same as boolean 1 / 0.